# How to get return value from call to perl sub from bash script?

Tags: bash, perl

I am calling a perl script from a bash script. I want to obtain the return value that the perl script returns in the bash script in order to act on it. When I have the following, the output is a blank line to the console when I expect it to be "good".

**bashThing.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

ARG="valid"
VAL=$(perl -I. -MperlThing -e "perlThing::isValid ${ARG}")
echo $VAL
```

**perlThing.pm**

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

package perlThing;

sub isValid
{
  my $arg = shift;
  if($arg == "valid")
  {
    return "good";
  }
  else
  {
    return "bad";
  }
}

1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect the value `good` or `bad` in `$VAR`, then you should `print` them not `return` them.

Other than `print`ed stuff, the perl process can pass only integer `return` values to calling program. And you can check that using `$?` in bash script, this variable stores the `return` value of last run process.

Comment: The Bash variable that stores the return code should be `$?`, not `$@`. Can you please check?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't have Perl `warnings` enabled completely.  You would have seen several warnings.  I enabled warnings both in bash (using `-w` on the Perl one-liner), and in Perl with `use warnings;`.  The shebang line is ignored in the `.pm` file since it is not being executed as a script.

`isValid` returned a string, but you were ignoring the returned value.  To fix that, use `print` in the one-liner.

You also needed to pass the value to `isValid` properly.

Lastly, you need to use `eq` instead of `==` for string comparison.

**bash:**

```
#!/bin/bash

ARG="valid"
VAL=$(perl -w -I. -MperlThing -e "print perlThing::isValid(q(${ARG}))")
echo $VAL
```

**Perl:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package perlThing;

sub isValid
{
  my $arg = shift;
  if($arg eq "valid")
  {
    return "good";
  }
  else
  {
    return "bad";
  }
}

1;
```